# Azure requests being processed by staging after slot swap

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

We have an App Service that hosts our website.

The website makes REST calls to our backend which is a Cloud Service (classic) web role running on two instances (behind one public IP).

We have one deployment slot, for the Cloud Service we deploy to the staging slot and when we're happy we swap staging and live slots.

Since I've increased the instance count from 1 to 2 in the Cloud Service it appears that swapping slots has little/no effect with most requests from the website still hitting the older instances (now staging). I've tried leaving it for 20+ hours and the picture remains the same. Now all 4 instances in both slots seem to be getting requests with the lion share hitting staging.

When I stop staging all requests go to the live slot.

Why is this happening? When I swap live/staging I expect staging to not get any more requests.

Answer (score 0):

During swap,  the virtual IP addresses (VIPs) of Staging and Production for the deployments will be changed. I am sure that after swapped, the old instances can't be accessed using the production IP address. Please check whether there are other clients which accessed your old instances using the staging IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but our CloudService (backend) is only accessed by our AppService (front-end) via a DNS entry that points to the public IP of the production slot.